# What's the purpose of the method onItemAtFrontLoaded() for paging library BoundaryCallback?

Tags: android, android-paging

I just had a look at the **paging library** and I found the **BoundaryCallback** has three methods. For one of the methods named **onItemAtFrontLoaded()**, the documentation says

```
Called when the item at the front of the PagedList has been loaded, and access has occurred within prefetchDistance of it.
```

I'm not quite sure about when this method will be invoked and can someone give me a detailed example about it?

Answer (score 6):

This method will be called when the library loads the "front" item of the list.

It is useful for bidirectional lists.

It lets you add more items to the front of the list, to let the user continue scrolling.

Imagine that you have a calendar App. You start at the current date. You can scroll down to future events, but you can also scroll up to see past events.